# Is there a way to kill all running cocos2d acions

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I need to kill running actions for various sprites.

Does cocos2d provide a way of calling a sprite and killing its actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
[someSprite stopAllActions];
```